# Conflict gradle version to implementation and SDK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8m1b.png) when I follow some projects on YouTube. This also seems to happen when I follow projects with SDK 31.

Is there any way I can know which version I should use for a specific gradle version and SDK? Is there any documentation or website that can guide me or keywords I can use when searching for on this?

Previously, I only used ChatGPT and hoped that everything would be coordinated, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Need to see your both gradle files. That is build.gradle file in your application_folder, and build.gradle file in your application_folder\app\...

Comment: Apps targeting SDK 31 require Gradle Version 6.1. 1 or later. Go to Preferences > External Tools > Android > Gradle, and set the custom Gradle build to Gradle 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Since there is very little detail in your question, it is quite hard to understand what the origin of the problem is.

What is important to understand is that within an Android project, there are a couple of factors to take into account:

- The API level that application is set for
- The Gradle version for the project
- The Android Gradle Plugin (or AGP) version

Each of these components is either tied to each other or has other constraints that define which version to use.

If you look at the [Gradle Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), you can clearly see which gradle version is supported by which Java/Kotlin versions.

The AGP version is constrained by the [version of Android Studio that you use and the API level that your application targets](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin).

Once you decide on one of these factors, you can use the references to help you understand what you should do with the other components.